# Google Tag Manager integration with Spartacus app

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, spartacus-storefront

Has anyone successfully integrated/implemented GTM (Google Tag Manager) into their spartacus site?
I have added the standard GTM scripts needed in the index.html but need help with pushing the pageview into the Datalayer portion that I have read online.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is a topic that we're working on at this very moment.
You can track the progress here: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/projects/110